# Debugging eclipse e4 source code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an Eclipse e4 RCP project using the compatibility layer.

The targets include `org.eclipse.e4.*` plug-ins and their source code. For example:

```
$ ls org.eclipse.e4.core.di*
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.source_0.12.0.v20140417-2033.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.12.0.v20140417-2033.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.source_1.4.0.v20140414-1837.jar
org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.4.0.v20140414-1837.jar
```

The launcher configurations include the plug-ins without source code.

**Source code for classes within those plug-ins is not being found with *Navigate>Open Type* or when debugging.** In the debugger, I'm given a button *Edit Source Lookup Path* -- but I'd like the source path to automatically update when I switch targets.

I can make that happen by adding these plug-ins to the manifest of one of my plug-ins. However, these are not direct dependencies, and it seems inelegant to list these here.

Adding the plug-ins to the product configuration file does not appear to help.

**How can I automatically access the current target's source code within the `org.eclipse.e4` packages, when debugging, and when using *Navigate>Open Type*?**

Comment: Do you have `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search` checked on the `Preferences > Plug-in Development` page?

Comment: @greg-449 - I do now. Thank you. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You include the target platform plugins in the Java searches (including Navigate > Open Type) by checking the

```
 Include all plug-ins from target in Java search
```

check box on the `Preferences > Plug-in Development` preference page.

The first time after this that you use `Navigate > Open Type` or another search it may be a bit slow while the Java indexer runs on the extra source files. It should run normally once the indexes are built.